# var b = Object.create(a) vs. var b = a

Tags: javascript

In javascript, what is the difference between:

```
var a = { steak:5, soup:2 };
var b = Object.create(a);
```

and

```
var a = { steak:5, soup:2 };
var b = a;
```

Comment: You probably meant `create(a)`

Comment: I presume you have a typo - `var b = Object.create(b)` is differnt from `var b = a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that a is the prototype of b, not the same object.

```
var a = { steak:5, soup:2 };
var b = a;
b.peas = 1;
console.log(a.peas); // 1
```

vs.

```
var a = { steak:5, soup:2 };
var b = Object.create(a);
b.peas = 1;
console.log(a.peas); // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use create you are creating a **new** object with the given prototype. When you use the **=** operator, you **don't** create a new object, you just copy its reference to another variable.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

You can test your

```
var a = { steak:5, soup:2 };
var b = Object.create(a);

// vs

var a = { steak:5, soup:2 };
var b = a;
```

here: http://jsfiddle.net/augusto1982/a8zjg1to/